# What is the technical differences between "update" and "upgrade" with yum?

Tags: upgrade, updates, package-management, yum, patch

I frequently use the following when updating/upgrading RPM-based distros (CentOS, RHEL, and Fedora in my case):

```
yum -y update && yum -y upgrade
```

However, I'm not sure *exactly* how the two `yum` commands differ.

What are the advantages of `update` over `upgrade`, and vice versa?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [`man yum`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum):

> **update**:
>
> If run without any packages, update will **update every currently installed package**. If one or more packages or package globs
>   are specified, Yum will only update the listed packages. While
>   updating packages, yum will ensure that all dependencies are
>   satisfied. […]
>
> If […] the `--obsoletes` flag is present yum will include package obsoletes in its calculations - this makes it better for distro-version changes, for
>   example: upgrading from somelinux 8.0 to somelinux 9.
>
> **upgrade**:
>
> Is the same as the update command with the `--obsoletes` flag set.

Comment: wow. My `man`-fu has failed me :|. Thank Diogo :)

Comment: I imagine/hope OP already read the man page. What it results in is that upgrade will delete obsolete packages In practice, you generally use update or update `<package name>` for day to day stuff, and reserve upgrade for occasions where you are doing full system upgrade to a new distribution version.

Comment: More detail on ServerFault here: http://serverfault.com/a/298158/88886